# I am trying to link the comment author name to site url/profile/author username

Tags: php, css, wordpress, comments

I'm setting up a wordpress website where users can comment based on user roles.
I would like to link the name of the comment author to their personal profile page `(site url/profile/username)`.

I have almost 0 knowledge about PHP, and I know a bit of CSS. I have tried a couple of different code snippets in my child theme `function.php`, but none of them seem to work properly.
The following snippet for example, only links the comment author name to site `url/profile/user` ID, but I would like it to be site `url/profile/username`

```
function force_comment_author_url($comment)
{
    // does the comment have a valid author URL?
    $no_url = !$comment->comment_author_url || $comment->comment_author_url == 'http://';

    if ($comment->user_id && $no_url) {
        // comment was written by a registered user but with no author URL
        $comment->comment_author_url = 'http://www.founderslair.com/profile/' . $comment->user_id;
    }
    return $comment;
}
add_filter('get_comment', 'force_comment_author_url');
```

I expect to get the username and not the user ID. I've tried some changes in the snippet but nothing seems to work. I'd like to know what I am doing wrong and what I can do to improve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the inbuilt [get_userdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) function to find out the comment author username. I have explained the added coded in comments as suffix.

```
function force_comment_author_url($comment)
{
    // does the comment have a valid author URL?
    $no_url = !$comment->comment_author_url || $comment->comment_author_url == 'http://';

    if ($comment->user_id && $no_url) {
        
        $c_userdata = get_userdata( $comment->user_id ); // Add - Get the userdata from the get_userdata() function and store in the variable c_userdata
        $c_username = $c_userdata->user_login; // Add - Get the name from the $c_userdata

        // comment was written by a registered user but with no author URL
        $comment->comment_author_url = 'http://www.founderslair.com/profile/' . $c_username; // Replace - user_id with username variable.
    }
    return $comment;
}
add_filter('get_comment', 'force_comment_author_url');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it's now working! I just had to change display_name with user_login in order to get the username and not the full name. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Yes, that page has so many useful values to play with. The question seems like you were trying to display the author name :)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for saving my day.